# member is undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, undefined, member

I got this code, wich compiles fine is VS, but running it in Chrome gives 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined '

```
canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = null;

constructor(...) {
  this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");

  if (this.canvas == null || this.canvas == undefined) {
    // Freak out. The canvas element does not exist.
    console.log("The canvas element 'canvas' does not exist!);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Got canvas! "+this.canvas);
  }
...
}

Resize(): void {
    var screenSize = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };

    if (screenSize.height * this.aspectRatio > screenSize.width) {
        this.canvas.width = screenSize.width;
        this.canvas.height = screenSize.width * (1 / this.aspectRatio);
    }
    else {
        this.canvas.height = screenSize.height;
        this.canvas.width = screenSize.height * this.aspectRatio;
    }
}
```

The error is occuring in the thrid line from the bottom, but it would in any point where the canvas is accessed, I suppose. The if statement in the constructor does not freak out.
I came from Java, and thus wanted to do do typescript instead of javascript, to have something a bit more familliar, but I'm quite baffeled so far c:

Comment: Can you post how you are calling the function?

Comment: I'm trying to have a listener in the window call it with window.addEventListener("resize", this.Resize, false);

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment says you are calling it like this:
window.addEventListener("resize", this.Resize, false);

If you change it to this it would work correctly:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => { this.Resize() }, false);
```

You can also change the Resize function to this (which will save the "this" context):

```
private Resize = () => {
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you very much!